# how to make the numbers of endnotes superscript?

Tags: superscripts, endnotes

In the following TeX, how to make the numbers of endnotes superscript?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backref]{enotez}      % <-- instead of \usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{changepage}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter % <-Added code from here
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother


\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\keyword}{\textit}{}{}{}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing

\begin{document}


But, in either of the above ways is it defined, why not to take the constraints as securing information too?\footnote{The question was brought up to my attention by John.} 

\clearpage
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renew the `\enmark` command (end of page 6 in the package manual).

Here's a reformatted version of your example, note that `hyperref` should be loaded last.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[backref]{enotez}      % <-- instead of \usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\let\footnote=\endnote
\renewcommand\enmark[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\frenchspacing

\makeatletter % <-Added code from here
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother


\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\patchcmd{\keyword}{\textit}{\textnormal}{}{\ddt}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}


But, in either of the above ways is it defined, 
why not to take the constraints as securing 
information too?\footnote{The question was 
brought up to my attention by John.} 

\clearpage
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

I suggest *not* to load `times`, but to prefer `newtxtext` and the accompanying `newtxmath` for math.

[image]